# How to return boolean value from BigQuery in Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-bigquery

I'm a new to BigQuery . I want to return boolean value from BigQuery. In this case , I want to output "True". In order to do this , I tried items() method as this article below says but I can't get the point how to use this method on my code. When it comes to getting value from this schema , Could anyone give me advice ?? or how should I search it ??

https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.table.Row.html

【This app functions】
takes request parameter and passes them to BigQuery and return True or False base on parameter to Client

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from google.cloud import bigquery


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def get_request():
    request_luid = request.args.get('luid') or ''
    client = bigquery.Client()
    query = """SELECT EXISTS(
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM `test-266778.conversion_log.conversion_log_2020*` as p
                    WHERE p.luid = '{}'
                    AND p.orderid != '' limit 1000)""".format(request_luid)


    job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
        query_parameters=[
            bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter("request_luid", "STRING", request_luid)
        ]
    )

    query_job = client.query(query)
    query_res = query_job.result()

    for row in query_res:
        return str(row)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

```
【The result of the code above from Python file】

Row((True,), {'f0_': 0})


【On GCP console】

Row | f0_
1   | True ← This value should be output
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the return statement:

```
for row in query_res:
    return row[0]
```

Comment: Sorry for too late response. I have solved with your advice . Thank you so much